# PHP MySQL +1 to value failing

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code which works in essence, but fails to add one to the value stored in a MySQL Database.
The aim is that a word is picked from a text file, the scripts check if it is in the database already and if it is, add 1 to the relevant row in the database. All of this works except for the +1, which just adds an arbitrary number!

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect to MySQL database. ' . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('decode',$connection);

$text = file_get_contents('text.txt') or die ('SYSTEM ERROR');
    $words = explode(" ", $text);
    foreach ($words as $word){
        $word = explode("\n", $word);
        foreach ($word as $single){
                echo $single;
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wordsequences` WHERE `word` = '".$single."'");
                if( $res = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ){//already in reference
                    $previousWord = $res['previousWord'];
                    $occurence = $res['occurence'];
                    $newOccurence = $res['occurence'];
                    $newOccurence = intval(++$newOccurence);
                    $newOccurence = mysql_real_escape_string($newOccurence);
                    echo $newOccurence;
                    $sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `decode`.`wordsequences` SET occurence = $newOccurence WHERE `word` = '".$single."' AND `previousWord` = '".$previousWord."' AND `occurence` = '".$occurence."' LIMIT 1;");
                } else {//not in reference

                }
                echo '<hr>';
        }
    }
```

Here are a few sample values for 'occurence' in the database starting at 1:
1
10
19
28
But each time, `echo $newOccurence` results in the correct next digit.

Can anybody see anything dreadfully wrong with what I have here???

PS. I have tried the direct query `UPDATE xyz SET occurence = occurence + 1 WHERE ...` but to no avail, also my field type is set at int(11). The direct query works in phpMyAdmin, but not in the php...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it's not a number, use `intval` to convert to integer `intval($res['occurence'])`

Comment: ++$newOccurence is set to intval, thats what is so annoying about it not working!

Comment: If `$newOccurence` is an integer, then `++` won't do nothing, use in the line before the `intval`, this way: `$newOccurence = intval($res['occurence']);$newOccurence++;`

Comment: As in the question, all of the different versions echo the correct value, just fail to insert it into the db

Comment: Mmmm then it seems an error in your query perhaps the last semicolon or quotes in `$occurence`? Try removing both

Comment: Have u tried to cover your sql code in single quote?

Comment: I mean this one UPDATE xyz SET occurence = occurence + 1 WHERE ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect to MySQL database. ' . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('decode',$connection);

$text = file_get_contents('text.txt') or die ('SYSTEM ERROR');
$words = explode(" ", $text);
foreach ($words as $word){
    $word = explode("\n", $word);
    foreach ($word as $single){
            echo $single;
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wordsequences` WHERE `word` = '".$single."'");
            if( $res = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ){//already in reference
                $previousWord = $res['previousWord'];
                $occurence = $res['occurence'];

                // changed here
                $newOccurence = (int)$res['occurence'];
                $newOccurence++;

                echo $newOccurence;
                $sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `decode`.`wordsequences` SET occurence = $newOccurence WHERE `word` = '".$single."' AND `previousWord` = '".$previousWord."' AND `occurence` = '".$occurence."' LIMIT 1;");
            } else {//not in reference

            }
            echo '<hr>';
```

Comment: No sorry, it's still not behaving! :(

Answer (score 0):

you missed quote on `$newOccurence` variable try change

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `decode`.`wordsequences` SET occurence = $newOccurence WHERE `word` = '".$single."' AND `previousWord` = '".$previousWord."' AND `occurence` = '".$occurence."' LIMIT 1;");
```

to

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `decode`.`wordsequences` SET occurence = '$newOccurence' WHERE `word` = '".$single."' AND `previousWord` = '".$previousWord."' AND `occurence` = '".$occurence."' LIMIT 1;");
```

or

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `decode`.`wordsequences` SET occurence = '".$newOccurence."' WHERE `word` = '".$single."' AND `previousWord` = '".$previousWord."' AND `occurence` = '".$occurence."' LIMIT 1;");
```

For increase :-

```
$newOccurence = $res['occurence'];
$newOccurence = $newOccurence+1;
```

Comment: If field is integer, theres no need to put quotes on field

Comment: but you can use single quote also for this

Answer (score 0):

You can do the increment directly in MySQL.

```
UPDATE `decode`.`wordsequences` SET `occurence` = `occurence` +1  WHERE ...
```

Also I recommend you have a primary key in your tables, good for updating:

```
UPDATE table SET ... WHERE table_id = '161'
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `decode`.`wordsequences` SET `occurence` = '".$newOccurence."' WHERE `word` = '".$single."' AND `previousWord` = '".$previousWord."' AND `occurence` = '".$occurence."' LIMIT 1;");
```